# Does Raspberri Pi recover from throttling?

Tags: voltage

I have a Raspberry Pi (3B+) in a setup, where during boot process may a small undervoltage occur (under certain conditions). However, I found out, that it never leaves the "throttled" state after.

dmesg shows usually one set of lines like

```
[   99.990070] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
[  108.309618] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
```

However, the throttled flag `throttled=0x50000` remains there. I tested the voltage on both 5V pins and 3.3V pins with a good voltmeter and then even oscilloscope and the voltage is perfect and steady without oscillations .

Is there any way how to tell it "You are good" besides rebooting which is not an option for me?

Comment: In the flag, `throttled=0x50000`, the word **throttled** is [*past tense*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/past%20tense). In other words, `throttled=0x50000` means the undervoltage event has come and gone - the event that triggered the dmesg entry no longer exists.

Comment: As per the link in Milliway's post, if the system were currently in the throttled-because-of-undervoltage state, the flag would include 0x5 (as it does in the dmesg log from when it happened).

Answer (score 1):

`throttled=0x50000` means:-

```
Under-voltage has occurred
Throttling has occurred
```

See https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/os.html#vcgencmd

AFAIK there is no way to reset it as it is reporting an historic event.

Just ignore it (but the real solution is to fix the PSU)

This is NOT "a small undervoltage" - the voltage is < 4.63±0.07V which is way below the recommended minimum.
See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Comment: So, if a software like OctoPI claims that the system is throttled based on `throttled!=0x0` record, and wont work/update/whatever even though everything is OK (for hours, there is only the `throttled=0x50000`, it is a problem of that software, not the PI.

Thank you.